# How to properly set rails secret_key_base in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a rails app that will run on 3 web instances behind a load balancer.
I understand that the `secret_key_base` must be the same across the 3 instances.

Whats a good way to keep it synced without having to set the environment variable manualy on each instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize them during deploy of your Rails application (i.e. put it to .bash_profile or define env variable in command which run your Rails server, etc.) or during provisioning your servers use such tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, etc.

You have a lot of ways to make it automatically. Just choose one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only going to be 3 instances that's not a key than ever changes so you could set it once in `/etc/environnement` on 3 instances and forget it.

If you are planning on deploying more instances I would suggest you to try https://www.docker.com/ you will have an automatic deployment system that lets you set specifics